# `__annotations__` doesn't return as expected

Tags: python-3.x

I was just playing around with the `__annotations__` function and I tried this -

```
def function() -> float:

    print('I always return a `float` type data!')
```

the output of `print(function.__annotations__)` is `{'return': float}`.

How can I make it print `{'return': <class 'float'>}`

Comment: What do you mean? For the function you provided `print(function.__annotations__)` prints  `{'return': <class 'list'>}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you need to update your python version.I'm using python 3.7.7,it works fine to me

code:

```
def function() -> float:
    print('I always return a `float` type data!')

print(function.__annotations__)
```

result:

```
{'return': <class 'float'>}
```